# C-type pointer to floats changes after returning from function in python

Tags: python, c, ctypes, yolo

I'm currently working on a Darknet/YOLO project which detects objects from images received from a live stream using opencv in python. To detect object, the opencv image, which is simply a numpy array with shape `(height, width, color_channels)` has to be converted into a format that Darknet  (written in c) can read (an IMAGE class defined in Darknet with a data attribute of type *float). For this I have written the following code in python:

```py
    h, w, c = input_frame.shape
    # create a flattened image and normalize by devision by 255.
    # NOTE transpose(2, 0, 1) permutes the axes from 0,1,2 to 2,0,1 (clockwise cycle)
    flattened_image = input_frame.transpose(2, 0, 1).flatten().astype(np.float32)/255.
    # create a C type pointer
    c_float_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float) # define LP_c_float type
    c_float_p_frame = flattened_image.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p) # cast to LP_c_float
    # create empty C_IMAGE type object and then set data to c_float_p_frame
    C_IMAGE_frame = dn.make_image(w, h, c)
    C_IMAGE_frame.data = c_float_p_frame
```

(Note that `dn` is the darknet interface and is imported somewhere above, but this isn't  the problem so it's not very important)

The C_IMAGE_frame object is then passed to the network. **IMPORTANT: This code works**. However here is the kicker, if I pack the exact same code into a function, I get access violation errors (i.e. segfaults) after the image is passed to Darknet. I initially wrote this code inline in a test script and everything worked, so when I started cleaning up my code I packed the above code block into the following function:

```py
def np_image_to_c_IMAGE(input_frame):
    """
    parameters
    ==========
    input_frame: ndarray            (opencv image)

    returns
    ==========
    C_IMAGE_frame: C IMAGE object   (implimented in darknet)
    converts a numpy image (w x h x c dim ndarray) to a C type IMAGE
    defined in darknet. Returns a pointer.
    """
    h, w, c = input_frame.shape
    # create a flattened image and normalize by devision by 255.
    # NOTE transpose(2, 0, 1) permutes the axes from 0,1,2 to 2,0,1 (clockwise cycle)
    flattened_image = input_frame.transpose(2, 0, 1).flatten().astype(np.float32)/255.
    # create a C type pointer
    c_float_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float) # define LP_c_float type
    c_float_p_frame = flattened_image.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p) # cast to LP_c_float
    # create empty C_IMAGE type object and then set data to c_float_p_frame
    C_IMAGE_frame = dn.make_image(w, h, c)
    C_IMAGE_frame.data = c_float_p_frame
    return C_IMAGE_frame
```

I was initially very confused why my code was creating segfaults, but I ran some debugging tests and found the following problem: when accessing `C_IMAGE_frame.data[0]` (i.e. just reading out the very first value) within the function, I get a float, like one would expect, but if I do the same after returning the C_IMAGE_frame like so:

```py
#opencv get image and other code...
C_IMAGE = np_image_to_C_IMAGE(opencv_image)
print(C_IMAGE.data[0])
```

python raises a segfault error. I checked wether or not all the pointers were "returned" correctly and I saw that some pointer reasignment magic had occured.

```py
def np_image_to_C_IMAGE(input_frame):
    # rest of function...
    print(C_IMAGE_frame)  # output: <lib.darknet.IMAGE object at 0x0000021F24F6EDC0>
    print(C_IMAGE_frame.data) # output: <lib.darknet.LP_c_float object at 0x0000021F24F6EBC0>
    print(C_IMAGE_frame.data[0]) # output: 0.0
    return C_IMAGE_frame

# after C_IMAGE is returned in script
C_IMAGE = np_image_to_C_IMAGE(opencv_image)
print(C_IMAGE)  # output: <lib.darknet.IMAGE object at 0x0000021F24F6EDC0>
print(C_IMAGE.data) # output: <lib.darknet.LP_c_float object at 0x0000021F24F6BAC0>
print(C_IMAGE.data[0] # raises Segmentation fault
```

Note that the `data` pointer `0x0000021F24F6EBC0` changes to `0x0000021F24F6BAC0` so **of course** it will segfault, but why does this happen? How can I avoid this? Is this just some internal python trickery or could it be something else? I mean, if I return something in python, I *expect* it to be the exact object I passed to `return`, but maybe python ctypes breaks something or has some interesting implimentation that needs a workaround?

For now I pasted the code back inline into my analysis script, so my script is working again, but I would be very interested in why this is occuring in the first place and how one could solve it.

**EDIT** I've added a minimum reproducible example:

```py
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

class IMAGE(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("w", c_int),
                ("h", c_int),
                ("c", c_int),
                ("data", POINTER(c_float))]

img = np.zeros((1080, 1920, 3)) # h, w, c array = opencv image analogon

def np_image_to_c_IMAGE(input_frame):
    h, w, c = input_frame.shape
    flattened_image = input_frame.transpose(2, 0, 1).flatten().astype(np.float32)/255.
    c_float_p = POINTER(c_float) # define LP_c_float type
    c_float_p_frame = flattened_image.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p) # cast to LP_c_float
    C_IMAGE_frame = IMAGE(w, h, c, c_float_p_frame)
    print(C_IMAGE_frame)
    print(C_IMAGE_frame.data)
    return C_IMAGE_frame

C_IMAGE = np_image_to_c_IMAGE(img)

print(C_IMAGE)
print(C_IMAGE.data)
```

Output:

```
# within function
<__main__.IMAGE object at 0x7fc7f618ff40>
<__main__.LP_c_float object at 0x7fc7f49b1040>
# after return
<__main__.IMAGE object at 0x7fc7f618ff40>
<__main__.LP_c_float object at 0x7fc800777f40>
```

Comment: The address of the Python level object is not necessarily the address of the data. For example, something as innocent as ``a = np.array([1, 2, 3])`` ``a.data`` will also have a different address each time it is accessed – because ``a.data`` creates a new *handle* to the underlying data each time it is accessed. Note that the thing passed into your function – known as ``C_IMAGE`` and ``C_IMAGE_frame`` –  *does* have the same ID after returning it.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] perhaps?

Comment: Yeah I guessed it had to be something like that... I will try to to create a minimal reproducible example later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the data pointer in `IMAGE` doesn't keep a reference to the image data.  Once `flattened_image` and `c_float_p_frame` go out of scope the data is freed.  Store an extra reference in the image to keep the data from being freed:

```py
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

class IMAGE(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("w", c_int),
                ("h", c_int),
                ("c", c_int),
                ("data", POINTER(c_float))]

img = np.zeros((1080, 1920, 3))

def np_image_to_c_IMAGE(input_frame):
    h, w, c = input_frame.shape
    flattened_image = input_frame.transpose(2, 0, 1).flatten().astype(np.float32)/255.
    c_float_p = POINTER(c_float)
    c_float_p_frame = flattened_image.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)
    C_IMAGE_frame = IMAGE(w,h,c,c_float_p_frame)
    C_IMAGE_frame.ref = c_float_p_frame     # extra reference to data stored
    print(C_IMAGE_frame)
    print(C_IMAGE_frame.data)
    print(cast(C_IMAGE_frame.data,c_void_p))  # the pointer value
    print(C_IMAGE_frame.data.contents)  # data valid
    return C_IMAGE_frame

C_IMAGE = np_image_to_c_IMAGE(img)
print(C_IMAGE)
print(C_IMAGE.data)
print(cast(C_IMAGE.data,c_void_p)) # pointer is the same, but contents freed if no ref.
print(C_IMAGE.data.contents)  # crashes here if extra reference not kept.
```

Output (note the actual pointer value stored is the same, but if the `C_IMAGE_frame.ref` line is commented out the final print will crash):

```
<__main__.IMAGE object at 0x000001A8B8B5CBC0>
<__main__.LP_c_float object ddat 0x000001A8B8B5CC40>
c_void_p(1824215363648)
c_float(0.0)
<__main__.IMAGE object at 0x000001A8B8B5CBC0>
<__main__.LP_c_float object at 0x000001A8B8B5CC40>
c_void_p(1824215363648)
c_float(0.0)
```

Not very elegant, and I'm not sure why storing `c_float_p_frame` in `IMAGE.data` isn't sufficient to keep a reference, but storing it in `IMAGE.ref` is without diving into the guts of `ctypes`.